# Batch file cannot successfully run bash and open .sh file

Tags: bash, batch-file, terminal, sh, exe

I'm trying to run a executable file created by PyInstaller on a Windows 10 computer. Due to certain securities on my work computer, I am unable to run the exe with any Windows terminal (TgApi), but any bash terminal works for reasons I don't understand. To work around this, I'm trying to create a batch file that will run the exe with bash.

This is the .bat file:

```
title Batch File
bash -x Shell_File.sh
pause
```

and this is the .sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
chmod +x Executable.exe
bash ./Executable.exe
```

The error that I keep getting is `Executable.exe: Executable.exe: cannot execute binary file`.

Comment: Replace `\ ` by `/`?

Comment: What is preventing to run that .exe? And why it stop getting in the way when trying to execute it from a different shell?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `'unable to run the exe with any Windows terminal'`. Is it a GUI python executable, or a console application? I don't understand why you cannot run the exe using `cmd.exe`, _it's not as if you cannot use the cmd shell, you're using it to run the batch file to run the bash shell which in turn just runs the python executable_. Anyhow it would also help were we to have more information about your bash installation; is it WSL?

Comment: and why are you using bash to "invoke" a stand-alone program? Once you're inside a shell script (with #!/bin/bash), you just say `./executable.exe` . But this seems like really the wrong way around and the above Qs are very important to address. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found looks like this.

This is the .bat file:

```
REM Get the current directory and set it to CURRENT_DIR
for /f "tokens=* delims=/" %%A in ('cd') do set CURRENT_DIR=%%A

REM Set variables to forward to Bash Shell 
SET SHELLDIR=%CURRENT_DIR%
SET SHELL=%SHELLDIR%/bash.exe
SET BASH=%SHELL%

SET PATH=%SHELLDIR%;%PATH%

REM Pass variables and shell command file to Bash Shell
"%SHELL%" %* shell_commands.sh
```

and this is the shell_commands.sh file:

```
cd (directory with executable)
./Executable.exe
```